# pandas apply with parameter list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, split-apply-combine

I have a simple DataFrame Object:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((5,5)))
df["col"] = ["A", "B", "C", "A" ,"B"]

#simple function
def func_apply(df,param=1):
    pd.Series(np.random(3)*param,name=str(param))
```

Now applying the function result in the expected DataFrame

```
df.groupby('col').apply(func_apply)

    1           0         1         2
col                              
A    0.928527  0.383567  0.085651
B    0.567423  0.668644  0.689766
C    0.301774  0.156021  0.222140
```

Is there a way to pass a parameter list to the groupby to get something like this?

```
#Pseudocode...
df.groupby('col').apply(func_apply, params=[1,2,10])

    1           0         1         2
par col                              
1    A    0.928527  0.383567  0.085651
1    B    0.567423  0.668644  0.689766
1    C    0.301774  0.156021  0.222140
2    A    0.526494  1.812780  1.515816
2    B    1.180539  0.527171  0.670796
2    C    1.507721  0.156808  1.695386
10   A    7.986563  5.109876  2.330171
10   B    2.096963  6.804624  2.351397
10   C    6.890758  8.079466  1.725226
```

Thanks a lot for any hint :)

Comment: So you want to "repeat" the subdataframe, right?

Comment: That was pseudocode. I would like to apply the function with different parameters on the data frame. So basically a combination of the first results just with different parameters.Right now I added only one, but in my usecase, there are even more. I know that this would work if the parameter was inside the DataFrame then it could be added to the group by statement.PS: hope it is clear. Just added the expected df. The values increase with a higher parameter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IIUC,***

`apply` allows additional paramaters. You need to pass it as `keyword` or positional agurments using `args` with tuple. How you use the passed parameters is up to your imagination. I.e, it depends on how you write you apply `func` to utilize them to get your desired output.

Let's take your sample data. I modified your `func_apply` as follows to sequential process each group using the additional `params` and combine them into the final output:

```
def func_apply(df,params=[1]):
     d = [pd.Series(np.random.random(3), name=str(par),index=['x', 'y', 'z']) for par in params]
     return pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

Now call apply `func_apply` and pass `[1, 2, 10]` to it (I use `keyword` to pass `params`):

```
df.groupby('col').apply(func_apply, params=[1, 2, 10])

Out[1102]:
               x         y         z
col
A   1   0.074357  0.850912  0.652096
    2   0.307986  0.267658  0.558153
    10  0.351000  0.743816  0.192400
B   1   0.179359  0.411784  0.535644
    2   0.905294  0.696661  0.794458
    10  0.635706  0.742784  0.963603
C   1   0.020375  0.693070  0.225971
    2   0.448988  0.288206  0.715875
    10  0.980669  0.474264  0.036715
```

Without passing the `params`, apply falls back to the default:

```
df.groupby('col').apply(func_apply)

Out[1103]:
              x         y         z
col
A   1  0.499484  0.175008  0.331594
B   1  0.052399  0.965129  0.649668
C   1  0.053869  0.297008  0.793262
```